# MvvmCross creates new ViewController for cached ViewModel

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I have implemented a ViewModel cache for my ViewModels in a Xamarin.iOS project using MvvmCross v4.2.3. In short, I have created a custom ViewModelLocator that caches ViewModels, and loads a ViewModel from the cache when needed.

This works well for the VMs in that only one instance of each VM is ever instantiated, but the problem is that a new ViewController is instantiated every time `ShowViewModel()` is called for a specific VM.

Is this the expected behaviour? Do I have to cache the ViewControllers as well?

Answer (score 1):

This is the current behavior in the default Presenters in MvvmCross.

You can override this, by creating your own class, which inherits from `MvxModalNavSupportIosViewPresenter` or `MvxIosViewPresenter` and override the `CreateNavigationController` method.

You could simply return a cached `ViewController` in that method if you prefer that.